# Cannot get server response in route protecting service

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I am using angular 6 and I am creating a service to protect some routes, according to the response of node and the expiration date of a token.

So, in my working service, that checks for expired tokens, I add the following functionality that also checks server response.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor (
    private authService:AuthService,
    private router:Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ){}

  canActivate(){
    if(this.authService.tokenExpired()) {
      //added this >>
      this.authService.showRes().subscribe((data) =>
      {
        console.log('URL DDATA',data);
      });
      //<< added this
      this.router.navigate(['/cms/login']);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

The `auth` service that contains the `showRes` has

```
showRes(){
  return this.http.get(this.router.url).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
}
```

In the `app.module` I use the service as such `{path:'cms/profile',component:ProfileComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard] }`

and if the user is not logged in, node responds with `returnres.json({redirect:true});`

The angular route service does not let me se the profile, as it should. But it does not get the server response.

Instead of `console.log('URL DDATA',data);`, I see

```
GET http://localhost:4200/cms/login 404 (Not Found)
XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:4200/cms/login".
ERROR Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…<pre>Cannot GET /cms/login</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}
```

I am confused. How can I get the server response?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the whole code of the node middleware that checks for tokens and sends back JSON to the angular route-protecting service

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const user = require('../db');
const config = require('../db/config');

exports.required = ()=>{
  return (req, res,next)=>{   
    const token = req.get('Authorization');
    const key = config.key;    
    jwt.verify(token, key,function(err, decoded) {
      if (err){ return res.json({redirect:true});} 
      if (decoded){
        let dateNow = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        if (dateNow > decoded.exp){ return res.json({redirect:true});}
        next();
      }
      else { return res.json({redirect:true});}
    });
  }
}
```

I use the middleware as such

`router.get('/', validate.required(), (req, res)=>{...`

**EDIT 2**

I added simple `'Content-Type','application/json'` headers to the `showRes` function.  No progress.

Also the weird thing is that when I click a protected route, it redirects me back to the login page as it should, in the url bar I see `http://localhost:4200/cms/login`, the login page appears as it should, but errors are about the login page

```
GET http://localhost:4200/cms/login 404 (Not Found)
ERROR Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…<pre>Cannot GET /cms/login</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}
XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:4200/cms/login".
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Verify that your `localhost` web server endpoint is working as expected** i.e.:

   - a. Check that the endpoint is returning a JSON
   - b. Check that the http server is running (return `200 (OK)`) and not returning error messages (Commonly, `400`, `403`, `404` due to improper headers, security restrictions or `NotFound`, as in your case)

From what I can see, your API is not returning your expected token JSON data (server returns `404 Not Found`, which is the reason for the 404 error when you request from `http://localhost:4200/cms/login` and looks to be why your subsequent `subscribe((data) =>` and functionality is failing.

> ```
> GET http://localhost:4200/cms/login 404 (Not Found)
> XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:4200/cms/login".
> ERROR Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…<pre>Cannot GET /cms/login</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}
> ```

You seem to be getting a default `404` error `html` page `{_body: "<!DOCTYPE html> ... }`

[Here's an example of a 404 error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/thisPageDoesn'tExistSo404Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/thisPageDoesn'tExistSo404Error)

#### Edit:

In direct response to your question

> I am confused. How can I get the server response?

Your server endpoint may not be configured correctly.
If there are additional problems proceeding from this, comment or edit and I am happy to elaborate.

See [**Postman utility for API testing and development:** https://www.getpostman.com/](https://www.getpostman.com/)

References for more info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/thisPageDoesn'tExistSo404Error
- [Common REST API Error Codes | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes)
- [HTTP Response Status Codes](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/)

Stylistic preferences:

- Parameterised functions with explicit return types. (It's TypeScript!
  so leverage TypeScript functionality for nicer code!)
- Break up your function calls into self-documenting chunks in variables `const` `: explicitType`

Comment: Style-guide: I would also suggest explicitly typing your function returns to aid readability and consolidate your understanding of the functions you call, control-flow, so you can more easily troubleshoot in the future. E.g. To determine that the 404 error might be a server or configuration error in contrast to your an error in your `code`: "How do I get the response?"

There are other formatting preferences I would like to enforce on you such as per-line `pipe`able operators `.map` but these are just to ease debugging on StackOverflow instead of requiring a whole code reworkup by answerers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am checking the code right now again. I edited my question and added the middleware that checks for the token and responds back to the angular service.